# appengine improperly configured database error when trying to send mail (using django_bootstrap)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I am using [django_bootstrap.py](https://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/django_example/django_bootstrap.py) there are [similar errors](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-appengine@googlegroups.com/msg13865.html) but i could not find solution to it.  I am using django helper(please do not suggest non-rel)

What i was trying to do was, inside a static html js website attaching a feature of sending mail, through a contact form. The form would take the data, and jQuery would validate and make a POST AJAX request to the url "/sendmail/" the views.py i have the following code:

```
def sendmail(request):
    logging.info("here1")
    msg = request.POST['comment'];    sub = request.POST['subject']
    name = request.POST['name'];    frm = request.POST['email']
    sender = name + " " + frm
    logging.info(sender)
    a = mail.send_mail(sender=sender,
              to="to@example.com",
              subject=sub,
              body=msg)
    logging.info(request)
    logging.info(a)
    return http.HttpResponse("1")
```

I get absolutely no error when i remove the line:

```
a = mail.send_mail(sender=sender,
                  to="to@example.com",
                  subject=sub,
                  body=msg)
```

However with that line being there, i get the following error:

```
<class 'django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured'>: You haven't set the DATABASE_ENGINE setting yet.
```

I look at my settings.py file and try making some changes:
1 adding two lines as done in django-nonrel settings.py

```
   DATABASES['native'] = DATABASES['default']
   DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'dbindexer', 'TARGET': 'native'}
```

This gave a 500 error on server and the page did not open.

2 I tried putting

```
   DATABASE_ENGINE = 'dummy'
```

This works locally but doesnot work on server(appspot).

3 I tried putting

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'appengine'
```

This too gives a 500 error.

Please let me know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks messed up in all sorts of ways.  Don't use bootstrap.py, it looks outdated as it's trying to load django 0.96.  GAE now supports django 1.3.

Please don't use the django helper.  It's not being maintained or supported by anyone.  If you have problems with it, the solution is to upgrade to nonrel.

I recommend installing django-nonrel properly.  Keep in mind django-nonrel is a full replacement of django.  Most of it's the same, but some parts are modified to work with appengine backends.  You cannot take pieces of django-nonrel and expect it to work with normal django, without a fair bit of hackery.  The DATABASES lines in the settings file will only work with django-nonrel.

http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine

Django helper doesn't have an email backend that uses appengine's email API.  That's available in Django-nonrel's djangoappengine package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a database in your application, you can set `DATABASES = {}` in your settings.py file. This will fix the problem "You haven't set the DATABASE_ENGINE setting yet".